# How to load a vector from memory with up-sample in Neon with C API

Tags: neon

i'm new about **Neon**. I try find some instructions to do following operation:

```
int a[8] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
int b[4] = {1,2,3,4};
int c[8] = {0};
for (int =0; i<8; i++)
   c[i] = a[i] - b[i/2];
```

How can i Do that with arm **neon**, actually how can I load the array with upsample to Neon like `{b[0],b[0],b[1],b[1],b[2],b[2],b[3],b[3]}`

Answer (score 1):

you can do this by extending b[] vector:

```
vld1.32     {q10, q11}, [ptrB]!
vld1.32     {q12, q13}, [ptrA]!
vld1.32     {q14, q15}, [ptrA]!

vshll.s32   q8, d20, #32
vshll.s32   q9, d21, #32
vshll.s32   q10, d22, #32
vshll.s32   q11, d23, #32

vsra.u64    q8, q8, #32
vsra.u64    q9, q9, #32
vsra.u64    q10, q10, #32
vsra.u64    q11, q11, #32

vsub.s32    q12, q12, q8
vsub.s32    q13, q13, q9
vsub.s32    q14, q14, q10
vsub.s32    q15, q15, q11

vst1.32     {q12, q13}, [ptrC]!
vst1.32     {q14, q15}, [ptrC]!
```

However, it's so much efficient when done with vld2 and vst2 when loading/storing a[] vector:

```
vld1.32     {q10, q11}, [ptrB]!
vld2.32     {q12, q13}, [ptrA]!
vld2.32     {q14, q15}, [ptrA]!

vsub.s32    q12, q12, q10
vsub.s32    q13, q13, q10
vsub.s32    q14, q14, q11
vsub.s32    q15, q15, q11

vst2.32     {q12, q13}, [ptrC]!
vst2.32     {q14, q15}, [ptrC]!
```

Comment: Stay away from intrinsics. I know many people confused to hell by it. Once I explained them how NEON works in assembly, they finally understood. That's my honest advice.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But we need to write the code in C API of Neon -_-

Comment: Can you tell me the c version of Neon to do This

Comment: You shouldn't take SIMD so casually. Without a strong base in how SIMD works in the first place, you will end up in an obscured mess of auto-vectorized machined codes that performs worse than without SIMD.

Comment: I know that, But the deadline not allow me to start with assembly language.

Comment: I don't think there to be a compiler capable of vectorizing your algorithm to start with. Either you resort to NEON intrinsics that doesn't look much different than above, or you go straight for assembly.